# Parse packet bytes using Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I would like to parse the first two bytes of a packets payload using Scapy. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Are offset calculations required?

First the payload needs to be parsed though the following will parse the whole PCAP file, is there a more efficient way to obtain the first two bytes of every payload? [link](http://www.packetstan.com/2010/11/packet-payloads-encryption-and-bacon.html):

```
>>> fp = open("payloads.dat","wb")
>>> def handler(packet):
...     fp.write(str(packet.payload.payload.payload))
...
>>> sniff(offline="capture1.dump",prn=handler,filter="tcp or udp")
```

Comment: What protocol are the packets and their payloads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see. That looks pretty efficient from here.

You might try `fp.write(str(packet.payload.payload.payload)[:2])` to get just the first 2 bytes.

You could also do `fp.write(str(packet[TCP].payload)[:2])` to skip past all those payloads.

Alternately, you could define an SSL Packet object, bind it to the appropriate port, then print the SSL layer.

```
class SSL(Packet):
  name = "SSL" fields_desc = [ ShortField("firstBytes", None) ]

bind_layers( TCP, SSL, sport=443 )
bind_layers( TCP, SSL, dport=443 )

def handler(packet):
... fp.write(str(packet[SSL]))
```

...but this seems like overkill.

Comment: When specifying the offset I received the following:
`raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname) 
IndexError: Layer [None] not found`

Comment: Oops. I had a strategically missing close paren. Edited above to fix it. Apologies, but it's still untested.